# I wish to add customised branding at application level . how to do it?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using azure ad and wish to have different branding pages for login for each registered app. Currently, I'm able to only set the company branding which works on the organization level. I tried the application branding but it doesn't seem to work.

Please let me know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at present, can not allow any app registered in azure ad to have its own customized login page UI like in azure ad B2C. Add customised branding at application level is still in the plan.

Comment: okay , but I can see the azure ad application branding page . so Im guessing that's not working as of now?

Comment: @srijansaxena Yes,this is an unfinished function,you can vote it in this:).https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/39419713-allow-any-app-registered-in-azure-ad-to-have-its-o