# How to add logo, banner or text on application level to show on login page when logging in to an application with Azure AD?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, branding

I've created an Azure account and added an application to it.

On company level I changed the branding (added a background and banner to the login page).
This is working great.

But I would like to create a branding on application level.

Let's say I have two applications: app1 and app2.
When pressing the login button on both applications it will redirect me to the login.microsoftonline.com/....
After filling in my email, I'm able to see the on company level defined background and banner.

But I would like to add different background/banner (or text) for both applications.

So the login.microsoft... of app1 needs to show the banner that belongs to app1 and app2 needs to show the banner that belongs to app2.

Is this possible?

I noted that there is also a branding item on application level where I can add a logo.
However, when I add one there it will only be shown in the azure environment itself.

Answer (score 0):

At present, app registered in azure ad may not able to have  its own customized login page UI like in azure ad B2C  .It may due to some functionality issue in branding option.  You may See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65473854/i-wish-to-add-customised-branding-at-application-level-how-to-do-it)

You may give try   [Set-AzureADApplicationLogo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplicationlogo?view=azureadps-2.0) (AzureAD) by checking [guidelines of size and dimensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-configure#use-a-custom-logo) and by selecting an absolute path for file path.

```
Set-AzureADApplicationLogo [-ObjectId <String>] 

 -FilePath <String>
```

Otherwise You can provide any feedback or idea or suggestion here > [https://feedback.azure.com/forums](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/39419713-allow-any-app-registered-in-azure-ad-to-have-its-o)

Comment: Thank you. I will try that later. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, but when i click on any feedback link of azure.com (also the one you just sent) i just get a message with something like: thank you for giving your feedback. I don't see the actual forum.

Comment: Ya i guess , the site is under some changes or migrating to other site . You may use this > [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html).